# Performance upgrade to an update

Tags: sql, performance, sql-server-2008

This is an old legacy code/project. Can not change the [s] table or the [other] table.

I am looking through a piece of code and I was wondering if there is a way to make this run faster somehow. I do not think there is a too big issue with it like this, but since it is executed a lot, maybe there is a way to squeeze out some more time from here.

The [strcol] is a varchar column, which in [s] should only keep values that are in [other].[strcol]. All the rest has to be nulled.

```
    UPDATE  [s]
    SET     [strcol] = NULL
    WHERE   NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT [strcol] 
        FROM [other] 
        WHERE [s].[strcol] = [other].[strcol])
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add an index:

```
create index idx_other_strcol on other(strcol);
```

Otherwise, I don't think there is much you can do.  You can rephrase the query using `LEFT JOIN` or `NOT IN`, but without the right indexes, that probably will not improve performance.